# What is the difference between GLBoolean and Boolean

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

What is the difference between `GLBoolean` and `Boolean`

```
isData: boolean = false;// normal type

isData: GLBoolean = false;// GL type
```

[image]

> Is `GL` means gloabal? and those are global variables? And what are the difference between `GL data type` and `normal data type` in typescript?

Comment: It's structural typing i think, see typescript documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: @nithalqb I didn't see anything related with my question :(

Comment: Hi Ramaesh, If you run your code in typescript it will gave you an error, as there is no type GLBoolean in Typescript. And GL doesn't mean its global..Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: No. I am using typescript version 2.0 . I can see it

Comment: Sounds like they're type definitions for the WebGL standard. Given that assumption GL would stand for Graphics Library. Unless you're working with graphics you should stick with the normal type.